# Running application in renderPartial mode

Tags: yii

Is there any way to run the application in renderPartial way instead of loading all views by using the `renderPartial()` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to use your views without layout : you should simply set `layout` to false in your controller, e.g. :

```
Class MyController extends CController
{
  public $layout=false;
}
```

If you want to use this for all your controllers, you should create your own base controller class :

```
Class Controller extends CController
{
  public $layout=false;

  // and if needed you can override render method
  public function render($view,$data=null,$return=false)
  {
     // do what you want
  }
}
```

Then all your controller should extends this class ;

```
Class MyController extends Controller
{
}
```